# How do I opt out my details from Google-owned artificial intelligence?

Tags: medical-records

Recently it was revealed that Google’s London-based company [DeepMind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_DeepMind) [artificial intelligence would be able to access the NHS records of 1.6 million patients who use three London hospitals](http://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2016/may/04/googles-deepmind-shouldnt-be-sucking-up-our-nhs-records-in-secret).

Supposedly I don't want my health details shared with some AI program, especially moving my medical records (along with other 1.6 million patients) to 3rd party database for some processing purposes over concerns of my medical confidentiality.

How can I opt out my details from being harvested by Google-owned artificial intelligence? Is there any procedure of that?

Comment: Can I ask why you don't like it?

Comment: Basically I don't want my medical details and history harvested without my consent and flying around across the globe between different organisations and AI systems without ability to opt out.

Comment: but as far as I know, the data won't reveal who you are. It only helps serve the research.